# InnerClasses attribute

Tags: java, class, jvm

The [InnerClasses attribute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.6) description says that

> If a class **has members** that are classes or interfaces, its
>   constant_pool table (and hence its InnerClasses attribute) must refer
>   to each such member, even if that member is not otherwise mentioned by
>   the class. These rules imply that a nested class or interface member
>   will have InnerClasses information for each enclosing class and for
>   each immediate member.
>
> outer_class_info_index:
>
> If C is **not a member** of a class or an interface **(that is, if C is** a
>   top-level class or interface (JLS §7.6) or **a local class** (JLS §14.3)
>   **or an anonymous class** (JLS §15.9.5)), ...

You can notice from the second paragraph that a local class or an anonymous class are not treated as "members". That means the first paragraph isn't applied to local classes or an anonymous classes. But when i compile this code (tried eclipse compiler and  javac):

```java
package bc_data;

public class Pokus {

    public void metoda() {

        class Pokus_Lokalni {

        }

    }

}
```

**javap -v Pokus.class**

```
Classfile /home/jara/projects/bp/bc_data/src/bc_data/Pokus.class
  Last modified May 15, 2015; size 321 bytes
  MD5 checksum cf9cd7707c297e7ba43b8408a9ff6e2f
  Compiled from "Pokus.java"
public class bc_data.Pokus
  SourceFile: "Pokus.java"
  InnerClasses:
       #5= #4; //Pokus_Lokalni=class bc_data/Pokus$1Pokus_Lokalni
  minor version: 0
  major version: 51
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_SUPER
```

You can see that the local class `Pokus_Lokalni` is included in InnerClasses attribute even if it is not otherwise mentioned by the class `Pokus`, so it is treated as "member"? Or why the local class `Pokus_Lokalni` is included in the InnerClasses attribute? It is enforced by the specification somewhere?

Comment: *'So the second paragraph says that a local class or an anonymous class are not treated as "members".'* Well the second paragraph is referring to something unrelated to the first paragraph, so it's irrelevant. But I see what you are asking besides that.

Comment: @Radiodef: well yes, i will change it a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My thoughts here are that:

- The inclusion in the class file needs to be *mandated* for member classes for the purpose of reflection (because of e.g. [`Class.getDeclaredClasses`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredClasses--)).
- This is not so for local and anonymous classes, but there isn't a reason they can't be stored anyway, even though it's not mandated.

> You can notice from the second paragraph that a local class or an anonymous class are not treated as "members".

Yes, they are not members. They are still inner classes, though, so they would show up here normally.

Comment: That thought that they are still inner classes is fine, but than why specification explicitly says something about nested members (that they must have entry in constant_pool) and nothing about nested "non-members" (local and anonymous classes)?

Comment: I just want to know if i can be sure (if it is enforced by specification) that even not used local or anonymous classes will always have entry in InnerClasses attribute

Comment: As I said in the answer, member classes need to be available via reflection, so they need to be guaranteed to have an entry in the class file. Anonymous and local don't need this guarantee and I'm not aware that there is one.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the first statement of the "classes[]" section:

> Every CONSTANT_Class_info entry in the constant_pool table which represents a class or interface C that is not a package member must have exactly one corresponding entry in the classes array.

This means that all classes other than top-level must be included in InnerClasses.

Now outer_class_info_index section:

> If C is not a member of a class or an interface (that is, if C is a top-level class or interface (JLS §7.6) or a local class (JLS §14.3) or an anonymous class (JLS §15.9.5)), the value of the outer_class_info_index item must be zero.
>
> Otherwise, the value of the outer_class_info_index item must be a valid index into the constant_pool table, and the entry at that index must be a CONSTANT_Class_info (§4.4.1) structure representing the class or interface of which C is a member.

This means that if a class is nested (is member of another class) then outer_class_info_index must point to CONSTANT_Class_info of the enclosing class, but for local/anonymous class there exists an enclosing method instead of enclosing class.

In your case Pokus class is not obligated to have InnerClasses entry for Pokus_Lokalni. It looks like javac includes it anyway and I think I have an idea why.

If you have a local class then it is either used in a method that declares it or is not used at all (let's ignore possibility to access it with reflection). Unused local class seems to be a really strange and rare thing, so it probably doesn't worth effort to treat such situation differently. So javac may just add all local classes in constant pool (and therefore in InnerClasses).

Comment: Yes every CONSTANT_Class_info entry in the constant\_pool table. But to have that entry, you need to use that class somehow. As you can see, i didn't used it, just declared it. If it was treated as "member", than it would be enforced by the spec, but otherwise??

Comment: OK, now I see this, sorry for the misunderstanding in the first place. Looks like javac just issuing additional constant pool entry even when it may choose not to do this.

Comment: Updated my answer with thoughts on this.